# SCOPUS API filtering by exact source title not working

Tags: python, scopus

The following search

`SRCTITLE ( "psychological science" ) AND PUBYEAR > 2018 AND PUBYEAR < 2024 AND ( LIMIT-TO ( EXACTSRCTITLE , "Psychological Science" ) )`

returns only publications from Psyc Science published in the selected timeframe when ran in the browser search interface.

However, I am trying to set up an API-based search using elsapy python library.

According to [SCOPUS API documentation](https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/ScopusSearchAPI.wadl), "exactsrctitle" should be sent inside "facets" request parameter of the /scopus/search GET request but elsapy does not have that option.
I tried sending the full text as query (including limitations to year and exact sourcle title) but in the response I get publications with different name. The date limitation works though.

Anyone had a similar issue?